# Exceptions are missing args in backtrace

Tags: php

When I run the example code at https://www.php.net/manual/en/exception.gettrace.php I get no "args" in the backtrace, as there is in the example output.

Is this a PHP bug or am I missing something?

My output:

> array(1) { [0]=>  array(3) { ["file"]=>  string(25) "D:\www\project\index.php" ["line"]=>  int(79) ["function"]=>  string(4) "test" } }

I am running PHP 5.2.8.

**Edit:** The example output is from running the PHP.net's example code, with or without arguments to the function.

Comment: Can you insert the code that the exception was thrown in?

Comment: @Znarkus Read the question again, the code being used is that on the example page linked by the OP.

Comment: And what happens if you pass arguments to the function?

Comment: Yes the code is the example code from php.net. And if I pass arguments to the function nothing happens, I still get the above output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to upgrade to PHP 5.2.9 (XAMPP 1.7.1), but it didn't work. But when I tried on a linux environment running PHP 5.2.11, it did work. I posted the complete test code below.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

function a($a) {
    throw new Exception2('EXCEPTION MESSAGE');
}

function b($b) {
    a($b);
}

try {
    b('THIS PARAMETER SHOULD SHOW UP');
} catch(Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}


class Exception2 extends Exception
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $args = func_get_args();
        call_user_func_array(array($this, 'parent::__construct'), $args);

        var_dump(debug_backtrace());
    }
}
```

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

Hmm weird.

The following (a class) does work though... But it still should give the args, even if you overload it to a nomral function.

```
<?php
class Test{
    function __construct($arg){
        $this->test($arg);
    }
    function test($args) {
     throw new Exception;
    }
}

try {
    new Test('Yar');
} catch(Exception $e) {
//print_r(debug_backtrace());
 var_dump($e->getTrace());
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried it on my local installation, and it does seem to work as promoted, although i'm running 5.3 atm...

It still should give at least an empty array, even if no arguments are passed...

try googling for a bug on your specific PHP version, or search the [php.net bug tracker](http://bugs.php.net/search.php)